# YouTube ?showinfo=0 not working but working on scratch.mit.edu

Tags: html, youtube

I paste this code to Scratch site using devtools:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dwEpRL1RiD4?showinfo=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried, too:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="538" height="324" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SvOx7tA_Cv8?fs=1&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The video title and uploader is shown on all sites except Scratch site.
I inspected codes of Scratch site, but I was unable to fix issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: What type of info should be showing? And how? when you right-click a video?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is deprecated in 2018. Now not for use in websites except scratch.mit.edu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, it is only available for that site.